# Skeleton Plugin / Module Not found Issue after build

Tags: aurelia

I created a plugin and I uploaded to NPM by using this skeleton. When I try to use it the module is not found:

```
import 'aurelia-virtual-scroll'; 

aurelia.use 
    .standardConfiguration() 
    .developmentLogging() 
    .plugin('aurelia-virtual-scroll');
```

My plugin index.js file looks like below:

```
export function configure(config) { 
    config.globalResources('./aurelia-virtual-scroll'); 
}
```

In the same folder I have that aurelia-virtual-scroll.js file.

The error I display is the one below:

> Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-virtual-scroll/aurelia-virtual-scroll'.
>   at webpackContextResolve....

Should this happen? Am I missing something?

[Here is my base code for the plugin.](https://%20github.com/hmarcelodn/aurelia-virtual-scroll/tree/master/src)

[And here is the skeleton for webpack where I am trying to use it](https://%20github.com/hmarcelodn/aurelia-virtual-scroller-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your class needs to be imported/exported in the index and you don't need to import it in the main file.

```
import { PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-pal';
export { AureliaVirtualScroll } from './aurelia-virtual-scroll';

export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('./aurelia-virtual-scroll'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rabah-G. I tried that but it's not working anyways.


DEBUG [aurelia] Loading plugin aurelia-virtual-scroll.
aurelia-logging-console.js:24 DEBUG [aurelia] Configured plugin aurelia-virtual-scroll.
bootstrap c64c475…:136 Error: Cannot find module './aurelia-virtual-scroll/aurelia-virtual-scroll'.
    at webpackContextResolve ....